# CSS: How to create a background-image masked by a mask-image

Tags: css, svg, background-image, mask

I have a div that I want to give a regular `background-image` modified by a `mask-image`, so that the page background, which uses `background-attachment: fixed;` can "float" as if seen through a window, behind the div.

For the mask image, I want to be able to use either PNG or SVG.

Even if I use an SVG, I would rather not use the `mask:url(mask.svg#element);` method because the SVG artwork may not be simple clipping masks, but also include shades of gray in the form of blurs, gradients, etc.

I would like the mask to use the standard *white = opaque / black = transparent* schema. I believe `mask-mode: alpha;` is correct for this configuration?

---

Here's what I've managed to get working so far. The trouble is that it relies on an SVG `id` (instead of a whole image), and also the size is way smaller than the div, for some reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    color: #174;
    background-color: #def;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.masked-bg {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    
    background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAL0lEQVQIW22KQQ4AMAjC4P+PZlXnzZoYwVpypFjACsHmCtPlZwxAaCqf5XzWWPsB9TsMBL7veUEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 10px;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    
    mask-image: url(#svgmask);
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: contain;
    mask-position: center;
    mask-origin: content-box;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>mask-image</h1>
<p>with a fixed background</p>

<div class="masked-bg"></div>

<svg width="0" height="0"> <!-- sized to 0 because this SVG data is only to be used in the div background  -->
    <mask id="svgmask">
        <polygon fill="#ffffff" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"></polygon>
        <text x="0" y="36" fill="white" transform="rotate(30 20,40)" font-family="sans-serif">V e c t o r</text>
    </mask>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```